# How to save images with for-loop and list

Tags: python, image, for-loop, python-imaging-library

I have a folder with several subfolders. These contain different files. All files ending with "Red_Lines.png" I want to save in another directory (I work with Windows). My procedure so far looks like this:

**Create a list with all Filenames:**

```
import os
List = []

for root, Lists, files in os.walk("C:/Users/.../Old_Folder/"):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith("Red_Lines.png"):
            List.append(name)
```

**Create new List with complete Path and Filenames:**

```
k = []
for filename in List:
    k.append(os.path.join("C:/Users/.../New_Folder", filename).replace("\\" , "/"))
```

**Save Images finally**

```
from PIL import Image
for i in k:
    img = Image.open(i)
    img.save(i)
```

But now, i get the following Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/.../New_Folder/123_Red_Lines.png'
```

The error message confuses me. Of course the file does not exist yet, I want to create it...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use command line "copy" to copy your files and not needing PIL module (comment #2 in the sample code). and another thing is, your code cannot find the file you are copying to (comment #1 in the sample code).

you can try this:

```
import os
List = []

for root, Lists, files in os.walk("C:/Users/.../Old_Folder/"):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith("Red_Lines.png"):
            List.append(os.path.join(root, name)) # joining the root + name

destinationFile = "C:/Users/.../New_Folder"
for filename in List:
    os.system(f'copy "{filename}" "{destinationFile}"') # copy-command
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you try to open file that have not created in **Image.open(i)** where your **i** is the new path. The **Image.open** should refers to **Old_Folder**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).